# Is it possible to intialize array filled with zeros in member initializer list?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization, new-operator

I need to define an empty constructor of class Array, which has one argument that contains value of parameter m. It needs to allocate memory for m elements in an array and initialize it with zeros.

```
class Array{
protected:
 int* data;
 int m;

public:
 Array(int m);
};
```

Is it possible to initialize it with zeros in member initializer list, or it can't be done except with a for loop in the body of this constructor. I defined this constructor like this:

```
Array::Array(int m):m(m),data(new int[m]){}
```

but of course its filled with random trash values leftover in the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write either

```
Array::Array(int m): m( m ), data( new int[m]() )
{
}
```

or

```
Array::Array(int m): m( m ), data( new int[m]{} )
{
}
```

It is better to declare the data member `m` as having the type `size_t` instead of the type `int`.

Comment: Please note this only works with initialization to zero and not any other value. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization